# Disable movement in unity through WASD

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my problem is the following:
I have a Scene where the game takes place.
I also can move around through the mouse (like in Sims or something, e.g. when my mouse is in the left area of the screen the camera also goes there)
But the WASD keys also do that and i do not want that. 
Especially because I have a chat in there and everytime I'm typing something in there, the camera moves...

I tried to disable it through project settings > input and deleting the alt keys (wasd) but that doesn't help. (I dont know why as well)

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Code looks like this:

```
void borderMovement(){
    if (Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.width - border) {
        transform.position += vRightDirection * Time.deltaTime * mouseSpeed;
    } else if (Input.mousePosition.x <= 0 + border) {
        transform.position += vLeftDirection * Time.deltaTime * mouseSpeed;
    } else if (Input.mousePosition.y >= Screen.height - border) {
        transform.position += vUpDirection * Time.deltaTime * mouseSpeed;
    } else if (Input.mousePosition.y <= 0 + border) {
        transform.position += vDownDirection * Time.deltaTime * mouseSpeed;
    } 

}
```

`border`is just a float and the `v...Directions` are Vector3.

Comment: The code in your question has nothing to do with WASD. Unless you are missing an important part of the code, your current code or `Input.mousePosition` cannot move the object with WASD.

Comment: @vitoscal It's strange, removing those keys from Input Settings should work. By the way, it should be another option in there, called "type" (Key or mouse button). Have you tried with that?

Comment: I know, but none of my code is responsible for the WASD part, i thought maybe it has something to do with unity presets or something like that.
@Andreaジーティーオー Okay thank you, I'll try it with that.

Comment: I changed the InputManager.asset file and now it works even when i close and open the project again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to freeze the position of the player/camera?

If you look at the rigid body of that component,
expand the constraints menu.

I'm guessing freeze position is unchecked for X, Y, and Z.

What if you checked freeze rotation for X, Y, and Z?

I know its sort of unrelated but I have some code from an EnemyMovement Script that can be expanded to turn off movement of GameObjects if "frozen"

Enemy1Movement.js:

```
#pragma strict

var initPos : Vector3;
var enemyWiggle : Vector2;
public var enemySpeed : float;
public var isFrozen : boolean = false;
function Start () {
    initPos = transform.position;
}

function Update () {
    if (isFrozen == false){

    transform.position.x = initPos.x + Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * enemySpeed, enemyWiggle.x);
    transform.position.z = initPos.z + Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * enemySpeed, enemyWiggle.y);


    }

}
```

Comment: I fixed it through the asset file, but thank you very much!